# Comparing values of two different columns with a unique condition

Tags: vba, excel

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmiBF.png)
Assume column position is not fixed firstly both column must be automatically searched and then perform the below task.
Cases:-

In column 'C' a two digit value is present which leads to a seven digit value in column 'F'.
In column 'C' a three digit value is present which leads to a eight digit value in column 'F'.
I want to validate whether 'F2' and 'F3'  start with 21 and if no Msgbox 'Error in this row'. and whether 'F6' and 'F7' start with and 228 and if no Msgbox 'Error in this row'.

Thanks.
++ Code

```
       Sub CompareColumns()
    Dim lr As Long, n As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim strA As String, strB As String, str As String
    Dim NotMatched As Boolean

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Assuming your data starts from Row2
    Set rng = Range("B2:B" & lr)
    str = "The following cells don't match." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    For Each cell In rng
    If cell <> "" Then
        n = Len(cell.Offset(0, -1))
        If n > 0 Then
            strA = cell.Offset(0, -1).Text
            strB = Left(cell, n)
            If strA <> strB Then
                NotMatched = True
                str = str & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0) & " : " &     
 cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & vbTab & cell.Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Value & 
    vbNewLine
            End If
        Else
            str = str & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & vbTab & cell.Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Value & vbNewLine
        End If
    End If
    n = 0
    strA = ""
    strB = ""
    Next cell
     If NotMatched
     MsgBox str, vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "Both columns match.", vbInformation
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code you have create until now

Comment: I have posted the code which i got from "sktneer" a stackoverflow user.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are provided compares column A and B, not C and F. The code compares whether the value in each row of column A is the same as the beginning digits of value in column B and then print out all the different rows.

The code has some minor errors and I fixed it like below:

```
Sub CompareColumns()
Dim lr As Long, n As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim strA As String, strB As String, str As String
Dim NotMatched As Boolean

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Assuming your data starts from Row2
Set rng = Range("B2:B" & lr)
str = "The following cells don't match." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
For Each cell In rng
If cell <> "" Then
    n = Len(cell.Offset(0, -1))
    If n > 0 Then
        strA = cell.Offset(0, -1).Text
        strB = Left(cell, n)
        If strA <> strB Then
            NotMatched = True
            str = str & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & vbTab & cell.Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Value & vbNewLine
        End If
    Else
        str = str & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & vbTab & cell.Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Value & vbNewLine
    End If
End If
n = 0
strA = ""
strB = ""
Next cell
 If NotMatched Then
  MsgBox str, vbInformation

 Else
  MsgBox "Both columns match.", vbInformation
End If
End Sub
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks ! i am looking for a code which search the columns based on the headers because columns position is not fixed. Can u help me out ?